# TypeError: jQuery.easing[this.easing] is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add an effect to my link with jQuery but it only works in min 1.7.1, and I have another code that only worked in 1.10.2.

This code works only in 1.10.2

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var menu = document.querySelector('#menu-bar-wrapper');
    var origOffsetY = menu.offsetTop;
    function scroll () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= origOffsetY) {
            $('#menu-bar-wrapper').addClass('sticky');
            $('#latest-wrapper').addClass('menu-padding');
        } else {
            $('#menu-bar-wrapper').removeClass('sticky');
            $('#latest-wrapper').removeClass('menu-padding');
        }
    }
    document.onscroll = scroll;
});
```

and this work in 1.7.1 :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.block-content ul.menu li').hover(function(event) {
        $(this).stop().animate({ marginRight: "5px" }, {duration: 'slow',easing: 'easeOutElastic'});
    },function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({ marginRight: "0px" }, {duration: 'slow',easing: 'easeOutElastic'});
    });
});
```

When I open my site these two codes don't work and show me this error :

`TypeError: jQuery.easing[this.easing] is not a function`

`percent, this.options.duration * percent, 0, 1, this.options.duration`

What can I do to solved it?

Answer (score 1):

```
a{
    color: #666;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out; 
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
a:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

This way in css

Answer (score 1):

You have to include the **Effects Core** in the jQuery UI download builder to solve this error.